# Mysql handling with single quotes conflict

Tags: mysql, joomla

I'm using joomla to develop sites, but I'm having a strange error. I have a syntax error in the following code:

```
$q = "TRUNCATE TABLE ".$db->quote('#__csvi_available_fields');
```

Which give output on runtime:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE 'erx_csvi_available_fields'
```

But mysql shows an error:

> JDatabaseMySQL::query: 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near ''#__csvi_available_fields'' at line 1
>   SQL=TRUNCATE TABLE '#__csvi_available_fields'

The strange thing is when I run without quotes, it runs normal:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE erx_csvi_available_fields <-- works without problem
```

Any idea what went wrong here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As other have said the wrong quotes have been added.

When using Joomla's `JDatabase` to provide quoting there are two different functions you can call one for values and another for database, table or column/field names.

To make your example line work you need to use `quoteName()` as follows:

```
$q = "TRUNCATE TABLE ".$db->quoteName('#__csvi_available_fields');
```

The `$db->quote()` is used to quote values being used in the SQL.

You can read through `/libraries/joomla/database/database.php` for an idea of how the abstraction is supposed to work.

Comment: Correct answer with great explanation.

Answer (score 3):

don't use single quotes "'". use "`" (left to the numbers on your keyboard). normal single quotes are for strings, same as double quotes

Answer (score 2):

Single quotes are used for **strings**, you should use **backticks** for names.

From the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html):

> The identifier quote character is the backtick (`)

Also have a look at this Stackoverflow question: [Using backquote/backticks for mysql queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556237/using-backquote-backticks-for-mysql-queries)