# CodeIgniter: meaning of backquotes in CI query

Tags: sql, syntax

The book "CodeIgniter 1.7 Professional Development" has the following
example in the "Using Callbacks" section of Chapter 3.

```
$query = $this->db->
query("SELECT * FROM `user_data` WHERE `email` = '$email'");
```

What is the meaning of or function of the backquotes around the
table name or field name in this example? What do the backquotes do?

Thanks.

Also, another example in the book has the following:

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM 'users'');
```

Are the forward quotes the same as the backquotes in this context?

Are these constructs standard SQL compliant?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556237/using-backquote-backticks-for-mysql-queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backquotes simply say "this is not an SQL reserved keyword". They also theoretically allow using spaces and special characters in table names, although *why* you would want to do that is beyond good practice sanity.

Using them is generally recommended though to avoid ambiguity with column names like 'name', 'limit' or 'count'.

Comment: I don't get it. Doesn't SQL know which keywords are reserved and which ones are not? Also, the tables above do not contain spaces, so why would the backquotes be needed?

Comment: @JasonPosit SQL does, but the DB designer might not. If you try accessing a column named 'limit' without backticks, you get a syntax error.

Comment: OK, you are saying there might be SQL extensions to the language which make the names used by the developer already in use. I would never use a column named limit though. Would rather change user-defined names than place backticks everywhere.

Comment: @JasonPosit, No, mate, I'm saying that a table can contain a column named 'limit', which you will not be able to reference without backquotes.

Comment: Fair enough, although in the code above I have a column named email, not limit, and email does not conflict with the language, so the backquotes are pointless here.

Comment: @JasonPosit, Specifics don't matter much, the point is what matters. In the listed example, those backticks are simply there for best practice. It's a good habit.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a Codeigniter thing, but an SQL one.

You wouldn't use them in CI anyway, if you'd use active records. The framework will handle the escapes and stuff, so you don't have to think about these things - that's one of the reason why you use backquotes in queries.